# Is there a way to prevent Jenkins from stripping the style element from a build summary?

Tags: css, jenkins

We recently upgraded our Jenkins core versions to 2.222.1. Our jobs leverage Jenkins scripted pipelines. In the pipelines, we publish a build summary (i.e. createSummary step from the Badge plugin) that aggregates the status of the tasks we execute.

With the new version of Jenkins and plugins, the build summary is no longer displayed correctly. I tried disable the headers for the [Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) already with no change in behavior.

When inspecting the elements for the build summary, I noticed the `<style>...</style>` section we had in place with some custom css is no longer present. Before the upgrade, the build summary included this style section with no issue.

I tried moving what we had in the style section to "Extra CSS" from the Simple Theme Plugin and the css is now showing in the page. However, this made me realize that Jenkins is now stripping the `class` attribute off of all of the `div` elements that was included in the `createSummary` text.

I know there is the HTML publisher plugin that can be leveraged, but with our use case it is extremely convenient to do this in the build summary rather than a linked HTML report since what we are displaying is indeed a summary.

The Badge plugin did not have a version upgrade which makes it seem more likely the change came from the Jenkins core upgrade. Since this was only a minor version upgrade of Jenkins, my hope is that there is a setting to make this work so it can be backwards compatible with our existing pipelines.

What changed in Jenkins that causes the `<style>` elements and `class` attributed to be stripped out of the `createSummary` step?

Is there a way to disable this behavior in Jenkins so we don't have to make significant changes to our existing pipelines?

Comment: Maybe you find the Jenkins-JIRA interesting, in particular what happened in the release you mentioned, see [Search for Issues with `environment ~ "2.222.1*"`](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62033?jql=environment%20~%20%222.222.1*%22%20ORDER%20BY%20lastViewed%20DESC%20). A filtering for `createSummary` did not give further clues. My guess: The described effect might be a side-effect of some security-bug-fixing or something.

Comment: I also suggest that you ask your question directly to the developers at https://gitter.im/jenkinsci/jenkins# - I am positive that they would open an issue in their bug tracker for your issue.

Comment: @B--rian Thank you for the suggestions. I did search JIRA and found folks that ran into issues with the HTML Report Publisher from the introduction of the Content Security Policy, which I got too focused on looking into that new feature without any luck. Turns out the issue was with the OWASP plugin integration with the Badge plugin, which something might have changed in default values there or in the latest version of OWASP. I'm not a fan of answering my own question, but since I did finally resolve the probably posted it below in case anyone else might run into the same issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is insanely simple: Disable the OWASP Markup Formatter plugin for the Badge Plugin section in the global config by checking the box as shown here:

[image]

This probably is not recommended for a multi-tenant instance with users that are not trusted. Our instance is a private instance where we have control over all jobs and content so makes sense for our use case.